# Remove specific words from folders using batch scripting

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have  folders like:
Test.xyx.Example.1.0.0
Test.xyz.Example2.1.0.0
Expected Output:
Example
Example2

Test.xyz.1.0.0 will remain same with other folders, only Example part will change , which eventually be the folder name
Is there a way to remove Test.xyz.1.0.0 in for all folders using  batch scripting?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is very unclear, not to mention that no attempts were posted. 1. What have you tried? 2. Where have you failed 3. Are all the folders the same and contains Example? if so then renaming all to Example will not work. Way too many things wrong with this question.

Comment: Appologies Gerhard.. i have just updated the question

Comment: ok, now you edited the question. Does all the directories contain Example?

Comment: No it's different in other directories which eventually be a folder name.

Comment: ok, so all the directories will contain `Test.xyz` and `1.0.01`?

Comment: Yes,all directories will contain Test.xyz and 1.0.0

Comment: So all folders have 6 **tokens** and are **delimited** with a dot while you want to keep only token=3 ? Hmm, I'd iterate the folders with a [for /d](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) and parse the names with a [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).

Comment: To help make things clear, you should edit into the question a sample list of folder names (one per line, using "code" formatting) of both what you have and what you want. Even then, you are expected to have made an attempt at solving the problem yourself _and show that attempt_ together with what's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d %%d in (Test.xyz.*) do (
  set "dir=%%d"
  set "dir=!dir:Test.xyz.=!"
  set "dir=!dir:.1.0.0=!"
  @echo ren "%%d" "!dir!"
)
```

Run it and then if it looks correct, remove the @echo so that it actually runs the `ren` command.

Warning: this removes the substrings "Test.xyz." and ".1.0.0" from *anywhere* in the file, not just the start and end. So if you have files where the "Example" part of the name contains either of those substrings, this script won't work.

Gerhard Barnard Edit:
to log everything and catch errors.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 for /r %%d in (*) do (
  set "dir=%%d" >> log.log
  set "dir=!dir:Test.xyz.=!" >> log.log
  set "dir=!dir:.1.0.0=!"  >> log.log
  @echo ren "%%d" "!dir!" >> log.log
)
```

Comment: I am trying it however its not working.i have placed .bat file in the same directory.

Comment: I would change this `(*)` to `(Test*)`

Comment: Cool, that should do just fine.

Comment: @TechnoSavvy what do you mean? How does it not work? What does it do instead? Have you changed the "Test.xyz" in the script to reflect the *actual*  prefix of your folders?

Comment: Hold on, I see you mentioned that the files can be in sub folders as well. if so then change the first line to `for /r %%d in (Test.xyz.*)` also given that then the batch file should be at the highest level where you want to start search. In other words if you want to rename files in `D:\test\` and `D:\test\test` and `D:\test2` etc. you will then place the .cmd file in the root of `D:\`

Comment: sorry. meant change it to `for /r %%d in (*)`

Comment: Yep, I have changed the prefix and there are no subfolder which needs renaming.is there a way  to  pause at error . I tried pause however its not working.

Comment: Its not working.I am working on remote system,is that could be an issue? as this is working fine in local system.

Comment: TechnoSavvy, then you were supposed to mention that in your question to save us from doing work for you for no reason.